# How to cancel second function only if first function executes in C?

Tags: c, function, loops

The two functions are about 200 lines since its a bunch of case statements (and they do work properly) so instead of showing I'll just explain what it does. I am currently creating a game similar to checkers.

Function 1: Checks if user input a valid move. If they did not then it would print out "invalid move".

Function 2: Updates the piece that has been moved on the board and displays the new updated board.

In the main function I did a while loop so if user input an invalid move, they will be prompted again. It does that but the board would still be updated. For example: if they chose to move piece 1 to a spot that piece 3 is occupying, the board will update: piece 1's spot is now empty even though it printed out "invalid move". I do not know how to stop function 2 if function 1 printed something. 
Here is what I put in the main function.

```
    char pieceToMove, emptySpot;
    int moveNumber = 0;
    int piecesOnBoard = 15;

    while (piecesOnBoard >= 1, ++moveNumber) {
        //prompting user input
        printf("%d. Enter your move:", moveNumber);
        scanf(" %c  %c", &pieceToMove, &emptySpot);

        checkMoves(pieceToMove, emptySpot, all, the, pieces, ect);
        updateBoard(all, the, pieces);
     }
```

Comment: `Checks if user input a valid move. If they did not then it would print out "invalid move".` This function is trying to do too many things. Please read about the Single Responsibility Principle.

Answer (score 2):

Have function 1 return the equivalent of a Boolean value (1 or 0 — true or false, respectively, in C) depending on whether function 1 was successful or if it failed. Check that value before deciding to run function 2 (or not).

One way to do this is define a `boolean_t` convenience type and `kTrue` and `kFalse` values in your header file. These are `int` values underneath the hood, but this makes code easier to read:

```
typedef enum boolean { 
    kFalse = 0, 
    kTrue 
} boolean_t;
```

In your header file, declare that your first function `function_one()` will return a `boolean_t`:

```
boolean_t function_one(...); /* "..." are the arguments this function takes */
```

In your implementation file, you write `function_one()` so that it returns either `kTrue` or `kFalse`, depending on whether its work succeeds or fails:

```
boolean_t function_one(...) {
    do_stuff();
    if (some_step_fails) {
        return kFalse;
    }
    return kTrue;
}
```

Again in the implementation file, write the call to `function_two()` so that it runs only if the return value of `function_one()` was `kTrue`:

```
if (function_one(...) == kTrue) {
    function_two();
}
else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Something went wrong...\n");
}
```

Comment: Do I still keep function 1 as void?

Comment: Why not just `#include <stdbool.h>`?

Comment: If you're not targeting C99, then you can't use `<stdbool.h>`.